# Get IFile from IWorkspaceRoot and location String

Tags: java, eclipse

This is an Eclipse question, and you can assume the Java package for all these Eclipse classes is `org.eclipse.core.resources`.

I want to get an `IFile` corresponding to a location `String` I have:

```
 "platform:/resource/Tracbility_All_Supported_lib/processes/gastuff/globalht/GlobalHTInterface.wsdl"
```

I have the enclosing `IWorkspace` and `IWorkspaceRoot`.  If I had the `IPath` corresponding to the location above, I could simply call `IWorkspaceRoot.getFileForLocation(IPath)`.

How do I get the corresponding `IPath` from the location `String`?  Or is there some other way to get the corresponding `IFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path implements IPath.

```
IPath p = new Path(locationString);
IWorkspaceRoot.getFileForLocation(p);
```

This would have worked had the location string not been a URL of type "platform:"

For this particular case, notes in org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform javadoc indicate that the "correct" solution is something like

```
fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(new URL(locationString)); 
IWorkspaceRoot.getFileForLocation(fileUrl.getPath());
```

@[Paul Reiners] your solution apparently assumes that the workspace root is going to be in the "resources" folder

Comment: No, actually that didn't work.  I think it's because locationString has a format like this:

"platform:/resource/Tracbility_All_Supported_lib/processes/gastuff/globalht/GlobalHTInterface.wsdl"

but the Path constructor wants "a valid file system path on the local file system."

Answer (score 3):

```
String platformLocationString = portTypeContainer
        .getLocation();
String locationString = platformLocationString
        .substring("platform:/resource/".length());
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = workspace.getRoot();
IFile wSDLFile = (IFile) workspaceRoot
        .findMember(locationString);
```

Comment: +1: although it is not really an answer, it showed me how to get certain instances!

Answer (score 3):

Since IWorkspaceRoot is an IContainer, can't you just use `workspaceRoot.findMember(String name)` and cast the resulting IResource to IFile?